# Issues in loading dynamic player through script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to load a dynamic player according to the browser like activeX plugin for Internet explorer using object tag and vlc plugin for Firefox and Google Chrome using embed tag, so I have tried to include it in the script so that onload it can detect what browser it is and display the player according but unfortunately I'm getting the following error:

Unable to get value of the property 'add': object is null or undefined

Following is my code:

```
   <head>

   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"> </script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
        var client = "FF";

                        $(document).ready(function(){
                            checkIE();
                            startUp();
                            //startIt();

                            $(function(){ 
            $("#vlcIE").css({ "width": "400px", "height": "300px" });
                  });
                        });

                        function checkIE() {
                            var clientCheck = window.navigator.appName;
                            if (clientCheck == "Microsoft Internet Explorer") {
                                alert("IE");
                                client = "IE";
                                return true;
                            } else {
                                alert("FF");
                                client = "FF";
                                return false;
                            }
                        }

                        function startIt(){
                            if(client == "IE"){
                                    playInIE();
                            }else{
                                    playInOthers();
                            }

                        }

                        function playInOthers() {
                            alert("playin FF");
                            var players = document.getElementsByName("video1");
                            var options = new Array("");
                            url = "rtsp://184.72.239.149/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov";

                            var id = players[0].playlist.add(url, null, options);
                            players[0].playlist.playItem(id);
                            alert("playing video");
                        }

                        function playInIE() {
                            alert("play in IE");
                            var vlc = document.getElementById("vlcIE");
                            var options = new Array(":aspect-ratio=16:10", "--rtsp-tcp");
                            //var options=[":ts-csa-ck="+EncryptionkeyValue];
                            var urlVideofile = "rtsp://184.72.239.149/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov";
                            var targetURL = "rtsp://184.72.239.149/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov";
                            var itemId = vlc.playlist.add(targetURL, "", options);
                            var id = vlc.playlist.add(urlVideofile, null, options);
                            vlc.playlist.playItem(id);
                        }

                        function startUp(){
                            var player;
                            if (client == "IE") {
                                    player = "<object type='application/x-vlc-plugin' id='vlcIE' width='300' height='225'  classid='clsid:9BE31822-FDAD-461B-AD51-BE1D1C159921' ></object>";

                            } else {
                                    player = "<embed type='application/x-vlc-plugin' pluginspage='http://www.videolan.org'  id='vlc' name='video1'  autostart='yes'   toolbar='false'  loop='yes' width='400' height='300'                                   target='rtsp://184.72.239.149/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov' />";
                            }

                            //$("#video_holder").html(player);
                            document.getElementById("video_holder").innerHTML=player;
                       }


  </script>

    </head>

       <body>

       <div id="video_holder" style="border:1px solid #00FF33"></div>
          <button type="button" id="start" onClick="startIt()">Start</button>

        </body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your calling an function as an variable here:

```
if (checkIE) {
```

That should be:

```
if (checkIE()) {
```

And you've got to return an value from your `checkIE` function like this:

```
function checkIE() {
    var client = window.navigator.appName;
    if (client == "Microsoft Internet Explorer") {
        alert("IE");
        playvideos();
        return true;
    } else {
        alert("FF");
        hello();
        return false;
    }
}
```

( you also had an semicolon ( `;` ) at the end of your function. That doesn't belong there either

Also, you maybe wan't to start using javascripts `console.log` instead of alert. In that way, you're javascript isn't interrupted, but you can see it's path in the console

**EDIT 1**

You had some more error's in your script. After fixing that, i "worked" for me ( you can check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6N24S/) out to see it "working"

The problem was that you've got this piece of code:

```
if (checkIE) {
        var player = "<object type='application/x-vlc-plugin' id='vlc' width='300' height='225' classid='clsid:9BE31822-FDAD-461B-AD51-BE1D1C159921'></object>";
    } else {
        var player = "<embed type='application/x-vlc-plugin' pluginspage='http://www.videolan.org'  id='vlc' name='video1'  autostart='yes'   toolbar='true'  loop='yes' width='400' height='300'
           target='rtsp://184.72.239.149/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov' />"
    }
```

You've got an newline before `target=...` that's illegal. You also forgot an semicolon at the end of that line. So here's the working script part:

```
if (checkIE()) {
        var player = "<object type='application/x-vlc-plugin' id='vlc' width='300' height='225' classid='clsid:9BE31822-FDAD-461B-AD51-BE1D1C159921'></object>";
    } else {
        var player = "<embed type='application/x-vlc-plugin' pluginspage='http://www.videolan.org'  id='vlc' name='video1'  autostart='yes'   toolbar='true'  loop='yes' width='400' height='300'            target='rtsp://184.72.239.149/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov' />";
    }
```

I've also changed the alerts to console.log in the fiddle for easier testing

**EDIT 2**

I've got it sort of working now. You can check the code at [THIS PASTEBIN](http://pastebin.com/96ZZZuZV).
Only problem: It isn't playing any video.

**EDIT 3**

I've tested the IE part, and I found out that the `navigator.appname = Netscape`.

So in your `checkIE function` you change the check line to this:

```
if (clientCheck == "Microsoft Internet Explorer" || clientCheck == "Netscape") {
```

**EDIT 4**

Turned out that the browser check was totaly wrong. I've googled a lot and finaly found an working solution. If you check this [PASTEBIN](http://pastebin.com/z9c88KFT) out, then you've got an working example.

Comment: now it's giving the following error:Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'playlist' of undefined at the line:   var itemId = vlc.playlist.add(targetURL, "", options);

Comment: @Priya, i know. I thought that that would be fixed when you would test it ( i thought it was an limitation of jsfiddle...)

Comment: @Priya, why aren't you using JQuery?

Comment: @Priya, i've updated the answer, now it should work ( only the video isn't playing)

Comment: thanks!....its playing.....i've used:document.getElementById("video_holder").innerHTML=player;

Comment: @Priya, If this has fixed your problem, mark my answer then ( accept it). This so that others won't be bother with this question.

Comment: @Mathlight...still it's not doing with the new code...I tried to use document.getElementById.innerHTML=player too instead of:  $("#video_holder").html(player); even then I'm stuck....I gave border to the div to see but the player isn't visible div is blank....I'm not clear why is this happening????

Comment: @Priya, with IE version are you using? And what does the console say?

Comment: @Priya, do you still need help with the problem?

Comment: thank you!....the problem is resolved.....can you help me how can I record this streaming in vlc plugin???

Comment: @Priya, maybe this helps: [link](http://www.videolan.org/doc/streaming-howto/en/ch06.html)

Comment: @Priya, no problem. There's SO for ^_^

Comment: @Mathlight.....I'm again facing the problem of the error: Unable to get value of the property 'add': object is null or undefined 
the only change I made was I removed the toolbar and used a start button to play the stream.....I'm not clear why this error comes again and again......what is the reason...is this because of some jQuery library???....I'll update the new code

Comment: @priya, I think it's easier if you e-mail me all the code that your  using. That way I've got an better overview and can help you better. My e-mail address is: difrncestick[at]gmail.com